# "What {is / was} your happiest moment in 2015?"

Tags: tense, sentence-meaning, past-tense, present-tense

Is it correct to say

> What was your happiest moment in 2015?

or

> What is your happiest moment in 2015?

Comment: 2015 is over, your happiest moment is over. Therefore, it _was_ your happiest moment.

Comment: If you want to bring the question into the present, you can ask "What is your happiest memory from 2015?" or "What do you remember as being your happiest moment in 2015?"

Comment: *What is your happiest moment of 2015?* is fine.

Answer (score 6):

2015 is in the past. Therefore, a "moment in 2015" is also in the past. "What" grammatically means the same as "your happiest moment in 2015", so its verb must be past tense.

Use "WAS".

Comment: Precisely.  Upvote from me.

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone, take my upvote!

Incidentally Stanley, you could also say "What is your favourite moment from 2015?"

Answer (score 1):

Normally we would use *was*, because normally we think of 2015 as complete and belonging to the past, and therefore we would use the past tense.

Using *is* is possible if 2015 is thought of as "present." For example, if the person you are taking to

1 thinks it is still 2015
2 too drunk to know that 2015 is over
3 has time travelled back to 2015
4 has been hypnotized to believe it is 2015
5 is reenacting 2015
6 is always in 2015

you could ask her *What **is** your happiest moment in 2015?*